# Does a ViewModel have to unsubscribe from events of an object instantiated in the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm

I use WPF with MVVM. I have a `ViewModel` that instantiates the object `MyService` as a property. The `ViewModel` subscribes to an event of `MyService`. The `MyService` property is bound to some Elements in the `View`.

**When the `ViewModel` is not used anymore, will `MyService` keep my `ViewModel` alive and preventing the garbage collection (GC), because of the event subscription?** If yes, is there an easy way to solve this? Where should I unsubscribe from `MyService`? (I have no control over the one calling my View/Viewmodel though)

```
public class ViewModel 
{
    public MyService MyService { get; set; } = new MyService();
    
    public ViewModel()
    {
        MyService.MyEvent += OnMyEvent;
    } 

    private void OnMyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Binding will use weak reference to subscribe to events, so if you dispose of your VM correctly, then there won't be an issue. Having said that, the VM could be in Gen2 of GC, then it will linger there for some time, usually 10 mins. If you have a memory leak then I would suggest to use a proper tool (I used ANTS free version) and locate what is holding a reference to your service. Maybe another instance somewhere else?

Comment: @XAMlMAX `Bindng` is not using weak references. It's using a strong refernce to `Binding.Source`. In fact if you bind to a source that doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, the binding engine will create a static field to reference the source. As static memory will never get garbage collected, you would introduce a memory leak. That's why the binding source "must" implement `INotyfyPropertyChanged` or even better (in terms of performance` implement `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: @XAMlMAX But `Binding` is using the weak event patter in order to listen to `PropertyChanged` events using the `PropertyChangedEventManager`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should always unsubscribe from events, preferably in the event handler.

```
public void DownloadFile()
{
  this.ServiceClient.DownloadCompleted += OnDownloadCompleted;
}

public void OnDownloadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.ServiceClient.DownloadCompleted -= OnDownloadCompleted;

  // Do something
}
```

In scenarios where you don't know the lifetime of the event source use the weak event pattern or alternatively the `IDisposable` pattern (but the weak event pattern should be the preferred choice).

To implement the weak event pattern, you would try to use an existing `WeakEventManager` implementation (e.g., `PropertyChangedEventManager`). Or if non is present, you can use the generic `WeakEventManager<T>`. Since this class uses reflection to resolve and subscribe to the event delegate, it is recommended to extend the abstract class `WeakEventManager` to create a custom type.
See [Microsoft Docs: Weak Event Patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/weak-event-patterns).

```
public MyService MyService { get; set; } = new MyService();

public ViewModel()
{
  // MyService.MyEvent += OnMyEvent;

  WeakEventManager<MyService, EventArgs>.AddHandler(
    this.MyService,
    nameof(MyService.MyEvent), 
    OnMyEvent);
}
```

If you can avoid to unsubscribe from the event source or to ignore the weak event pattern, depends on the lifetime of the event source.

In order to execute the event handler, the event source must "know" the listener in order access the callback (or more technically the memory space allocated for the listener instance). The delegate therefore keeps a strong reference to the instance, which is stored in the `Delegate.Target` property.

If the event source `MyService` lives longer than the listener `ViewModel`, then the listener can't be garbage collected, until the event source itself is garbage collected or the strong reference is removed (e.g. by unsubscribing or setting the event delegate to `null`).

This scenario is possible e.g., when the event source is an aggregated instance, that is allowed to live or be referenced outside the class' scope e.g., via a public property or as return value of a method or the event source is defined `static`.

In your code `MyService` (the event source) is defined `public`. This means `ViewModel`(the event listener) has no control over the lifetime of this instance.
If some instance outside the scope of `ViewModel` with a longer lifetime than `ViewModel` obtains a reference to the value of this `public` property, `MyService` (and therefore the event listener `ViewModel`) will be kept alive, even if `ViewModel` sets the property `MyService` to `null`.

If the property `MyService` would be `private` and you would never return a reference of this property to a caller of a `public` method, then you should be safe, since the lifetime of `MyService` is now coupled to the lifetime of `ViewModel`. Destructing `ViewModel` will also destruct `MyService`.
In other words you must guarantee that the lifetime of the event source is either coupled to the  lifetime of the event listener (or shorter) or that there is "no" coupling between them a all (weak event pattern, unsubscribe).

You better **always** follow the pattern of subscribe/unsubscribe or `WeakEventManager`. This way you don't have to worry about object lifetime to prevent memory leaks.

[How to Implement the Weak Event Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/weak-event-patterns#how-to-implement-the-weak-event-pattern)

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. I was unsure whether garbage collection works when the ViewModel owns MyService. But It makes sense, because the ViewModel and MyService would both have no root object referencing to them, I guess, thus can be garbage collected. The issue left is the binding. I need to check whether INPC is implemented in this case, to be sure that binding happens via weak reference. I thought about using weak event pattern, but have never done before. Maybe I give it a try, just to be save.

Comment: In case `MyService` is the source of a data binding, you MUST implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The binding would of course work without it, but the binding engine would create a `static` reference to `ViewModel` to handle the absence of `INotifyPropertyChanged`. `static` objects will never get garbage collected and therefore have a lifetime that is bound to the application lifetime. This is a potential memory leak, especially if you create multiple instances of `ViewModel` because you expect old instances to be destructed by the garbage collector.

Comment: If `ViewModel` would live during the complete application lifetime anyway, then the only cost is the (significant) performance penalty for binding to an object that either doesn't implement the source property as `DependencyProperty` or doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. That's why view models should always implement this interface. You can move the implementation to a shared base class, that every view model can extend.